# Android: ListView with Swipe inside ViewPager

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

I have an activity with a ViewPager that covers the whole activity. Inside this ViewPager is a ListView, that only covers the bottom part of the fragment. The ListView recognizes swipe events (you can swipe Items left and right) but when you want to swipe a list item the ViewPager switches the page, so it doesn't work.
Is there an easy way to deal with this problem, so that the ViewPager doesn't receive the touch events that are intended for the list.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first idea is [requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent.html#requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent%28boolean%29) may help you.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
    if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
       listItem.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works well but when I change the data inside the ViewPager (and call notifyDataSetChanged on its adapter) WHILE swiping inside the ListView it doesn't work anymore (the ViewPager flips although I still want it to stay and just receive the touch events through the ListView)

Comment: if you debug it, is the `onTouch()` still getting called after the `notifyDataSetChanged()`? where did you include the `onTouch()`, in the listView, or in every one of the items inside the list?

Comment: onTouch() is called with ACTION_CANCEL and then it isn't called anymore. The onTouch() of the ViewPager gets called then. I have included the onTouch in the listView, not all the list items.

Comment: I don't know if it will work, but what about set the `onTouch()` in list items?

Comment: Could you be more explicit about where to add this code? I have a custom adapter that extends BaseAdapter, and my list is a ListFragment.

Comment: @Tom Macdonald, set an `onTouchListener` with that code in the view returned by `getView()` of your custom BaseAdapter.

Comment: Saved my day. Thank you very much.