# ViewPager Inside listView as a row

Tags: android, listview

I have placed a viewpager as a listview's row. but the list items are not getting displayed i have set fixed height to the viewpager.

My ListViewAdapater's getView()

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater mInflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
    if (convertview == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.vp = (ViewPager) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vp);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.adapter = new PagerAdapter(this.context);
    holder.vp.setAdapter(holder.adapter);
    holder.vp.setCurrentItem(0, true);
    convertview.setTag(holder);
    return convertView;
}
```

I have read a SO Answer [ViewPager inside ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674529/viewpager-inside-listview) that implementing viewpager inside listview is not advisable.  Now my problem is only the **first row is displayed rest of the rows are empty**.

Comment: I was able to find the solution with the following links of SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21334599/android-listview-with-swipe-inside-viewpager, Which helps to differentiate touch between list view and ViewPager                   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920459/placing-viewpager-as-a-row-in-listview/15071212#15071212,               http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173545/multiple-viewpagers-inside-single-listview-is-crashing   Which helps to set an unique ID to the view pager

Comment: Do you mean that if I set a unique ID to each view pager in a listview everything will work fine?