# Viewpager inside listview row

Tags: android

I have listview in which each list item contains some textviews and one viewpager. I want to scrollable images in each listitem via viewpager just like Airbnb app.

I have tried to implement it but problem is that each time in list adapter I have to create new viewpager instance, set a new id to viewpager. Also each time I have to create new FragmentStatePagerAdapter and set it to viewpager. The app crash on reuse of viewpager and adapter.

So is there any way or library available to integrate viewpager in listview??

Here is my code
I am using SimpleCursorAdapter for listview and SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder to bind viewpager adapter.

SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder

```
...

    enter code here
    listPager = new ViewPager(MainListActivity.this);
    listPager.setId(R.id.viewpager_id_base + cursor.getPosition() + 1);
    listPager.setPageMargin(-(int) (pageMargin * 1.5));
    listPager.setLayoutParams(pagerParams);

    imageList      = MainListDAO.getMedia(rowId);
    mediaAdapter   = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), imageList);
    mediaAdapter   . setCount(imageList.size());
    listPager.setAdapter(mediaAdapter);

...


listitem.xml
...
  <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtCommentCount"
                    style="@style/textStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/txtSending"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/clock" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgMute"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic__mute_small" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lytMedia"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_default_margin"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >
            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


        </LinearLayout>
```

...

Comment: You should post some code of what you have already tried, that would probably help to get you an answer.

Comment: [It might help](http://dallasgutauckis.com/2013/04/30/android-putting-a-viewpager-inside-a-listview/) *- thanks Google.* See [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920459/placing-viewpager-as-a-row-in-listview), [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21334599/android-listview-with-swipe-inside-viewpager) and [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173545/multiple-viewpagers-inside-single-listview-is-crashing) *- thanks SO.*

Comment: Why do you need to assign a new id to the viewpager? You should recreate the adapter if it's necessary, but you could just change its data set if possible. But you can definitely reuse the viewpager.

Comment: @rekaszeru I believe this is because the fragment manager searches for the ViewPager by id and finds two (or however many you allow to fit on one page + 1 for the next view being inflated when scrolling), causing odd behavior of disappearing ViewPagers and crashes.  I currently had to implement it the same way as mentioned above, but it makes everything slow and has some corner case crashes depending on the fragment being used... (namely a map fragment)

Comment: Yeah its going to be more complicated. After a long time, I come to solution that instead of using viewpager, just use gallery component. Just override the onfling method of gallery to return false and all are done.

Answer (score 0):

I did try  implement the same, but no success.

I think that the app implements a custom component. It don't work in all devices eg: Moto G, Samsung Galaxy Note II. The items will be showed like a list and the horizontal pager will be disabled.

You could use [AndroidImageSlider](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider) library to implement each item in a Recyclerview. You must create a custom adapter that implements the `onBindViewHolder` and set the `SliderLayout` attributes in this method. I did it ... and works.